# During traffic generation from client to server, why does socket's send buffer queue get stuck at one point even when the size of send buffer is more?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, operating-system, buffer

I am trying to develop a socket congestion algorithm in diameter stack by comparing the socket send buffer size[default max size] and the actual bytes available in send buffer queue.

```
getsockopt(ainfo->socket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_SNDBUF,(void *)&n, &m); // Getting the max default size
retval = ioctl(ainfo->socket,TIOCOUTQ,&bytes_available); // Getting the actual bytes available
```

Testing scenario:

1. Start the client and server.
2. Once handshake is successful, start the traffic from client to server.
3. Block the packets at server's end using iptables.
4. Check the netstat output and check the send buffer size with help of ss command.

The send buffer size get stuck after sometime at a certain number. Example size of send buffer is 87090 [tb as shown in ss output]. The Send Q is stuck at some random number which is much smaller than the tb [for example : 54344]. Sometimes it increases till 135920. Ideally it should reach somewhere around 80k and then get stuck. Can somewhen explain me this unusual behavior ?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the peer executing any reads?

Comment: No. Peer is not trying to read when we block the packets.